# Can SQL Server transactional table have a surrogate key as its primary key, which has a child table?

Tags: sql-server, primary-key

I have used natural keys of transactional tables as primary keys but I was told to use surrogate key as a primary key. But this table has a dependent child table. I want to know what is the best practice to choose primary key of a table, when it has a child table- between natural key vs surrogate key.

If surrogate key is preferred, how would I derive this surrogate key into child table to make a foreign key relationship? I know we do this is in Data warehousing environment to load dimension tables first and then fact tables by doing the look up on the dimension table keys.

Please give me your inputs on what is the best approach for transactional relational database design?

I appreciate your help in this regard.

Thank you!
Varun

Comment: the `identity` property is often used as a surrogate key. It could be a FK in a child table just like a natural key would.

Comment: There's no best approach, it's a matter of personal preference.

Comment: Thanks Scsimon for the response! I can get surrogate using identity in Parent table. But I want to understand how would I map this generated key to the child table as part of the Foreign Key? For Eg: "Student" is the parent table and "class" is the child table. "Student" table has surrogate key as primary key with values:1,2, and so on.. in Child table, I have StudentID,classID, but not values(1,2,3,..).  Please let me know how can i map both the tables on surrogate key(1,2,3..). Is it possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Microsoft SQL Server there is no great difference between a key defined as PRIMARY KEY and a key defined as a UNIQUE constraint. Therefore there is no special advantage to making the primary key a surrogate.

A disadvantage to having a surrogate key referenced by a foreign key constraint is that you will usually need extra joins and lookups in code. Because any searches will usually be based on the natural key(s) you will need an extra join - or at least an extra index seek operation - to find the surrogate key value first. You will typically need to do that kind of lookup or join whenever you want to modify referencing rows in a child table.

If you insert rows to the child table immediately after inserting to the parent table then there you can retrieve the surrogate values without any extra operation. If the surrogate is an IDENTITY column you can use the SCOPE_IDENTITY function to retrieve the last-inserted value. Alternatively, you can also use the OUTPUT clause on an INSERT statement to retrieve the inserted values - useful when you are inserting more than one row.